# Deriving the gradient of $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at any coordinates $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

Let $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ be an coordinates on $\mathbb{R^3}$ s.t there is parametrization  as the following: $$\vec{r}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right)=x_{1}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{i}+x_{2}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{j}+x_{3}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{k}, \quad\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \in D$$

assume that $\vec{r} \in C^1$ and let $$\vec{r}_{u_{1}}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{1}}, \quad \vec{r}_{u_{2}}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{2}}, \quad \vec{r}_{u_{3}}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{3}}$$ define the basis $$B=\left\{\vec{r}_{u_{1}}, \vec{r}_{u_{2}}, \vec{r}_{u_{3}}\right\}$$ for $\mathbb{R^3}$ and Let $$\tilde{B}=\left\{\vec{f}_{u_{1}}, \vec{f}_{u_{2}}, \vec{f}_{u_{3}}\right\}$$ be the dual basis s.t  $$\left\langle f_{u_{i}}, \vec{r}_{u_{j}}\right\rangle=\delta_{i j}$$

define the matrix $g$ s.t $$g_{i j}=\left\langle\vec{r}_{u_{i}}, \vec{r}_{u_{j}}\right\rangle$$

Let $$f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ and $f \in C^1$ assume that $f$ is the function of the coordinates$(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ s.t $$f\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right)=f\left(\vec{r}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right)\right)$$ show that the grad of $f$ in $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ coordinates is $$\vec{\nabla} f=\sum_{i=1}^{3}(\vec{\nabla} f)_{i} \vec{r}_{u_{i}}=\sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(g^{-1}\right)_{i j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_{j}} \vec{r}_{u_{i}}$$

while $\left(g^{-1}\right)_{i j}$ is the entries of the inverse matrix $g$.

I understood so far that the matrix g is the multiply of $J^TJ$ but I am not sure how it can help me solve this problem

Comment: What is your definition of $\vec \nabla f$?

Comment: @ArcticChar it is the gradient of $f$ if that what you meant from me to answer

Comment: What is the definition of the gradient of $f$? Do you have that?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes I wrote it down, I think my main problem is to understand how $g^{-1}$ is looks like

Comment: Is anyone here have the explnation how does $g^-1$ is looks like?